# Convert a C# DateTime to JavaScript DateTime

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert a C# DateTime variable into something that is able to be passed into a Javascript function through NewtonSoft.Json.

At the moment what I am using is:

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss";
string modelFromDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.FromDate, jsonSettings);
```

However this does not seem to be working since when I use Chrome Dev Tools I get the error that

> modelFromDate is not defined

in the following code:

```
$(".go").on("click", function () {
    if (new Date(modelFromDate) < new Date(1994, 1, 1)) {
        alert("invalid date");
    }
});
```

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC.

Answer (score 0):

> modelFromDate is not defined

This is because you did not use `@` simple before the C# variable accessing in JavaScript.

Morevoer you can use `Date.parse`. It will return number of `milliseconds`, then you need to wrap a `Date` constructor around it as follows:

```
$(".go").on("click", function () {
    var jsFromDate = new Date(Date.parse(@modelFromDate));
    if (jsFromDate  < new Date(1994, 1, 1)) {
        alert("invalid date");
    }
});
```

Comment: OP's problem is not formatting the date, it's *"modelFromDate is not defined"*. From what I can tell they're declaring the date variable in C# and trying to access it in JavaScript.

Comment: `"modelFromDate is not defined"` this is because he did not use `@ `simple before the variable accessing in javascript.

Comment: Hey, I've tried adding a @ and it made no difference

Comment: @Zoe Have debugged it properly to see the value of `modelFromDate` in js code?